# Select 2 markup moving to previous row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-select2

I have a vuejs application that loops though an array and outputs a multitude of select2 elements. There is a delete button next to each element. When one of these elements is deleted, there's a bug/glitch which means the previous select2 value is applied to the previous row.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3oqsmw0z/1/

I delete the item by index as below:

```
deleteItem: function(index) {
    console.log('deleteItem');
    this.mySelects.splice(index, 1);
}
```

**To replicate the issue**

Select the first option in the first select, the second option in the second select, then the third option in the third select. Now, delete the second option. In theory it should now show elements one and three (two has been deleted). But it show number two's option selected. You can see it's the third element by the label, and if you look at the markup in the console it is the third element. Why is it showing number two's selected option?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you delete the second element the value for the third element is set again. So value watcher handler is executed. In your handler you try to set the value with jQuery:

```
watch: {
    value: function (value) {
      // update value
      $(this.$el).val(value)
    },...
```

But it doesn't work because this action doesn't fire `change` event. So Vue doesn't render any changes.

To fix it fire `change` event explicitly:

```
 watch: {
    value: function (value) {
      // update value
      $(this.$el).val(value).trigger('change')
    },...
```

I also noticed in your demo that your `select` elements are not initialized correctly. You pass:

```
mySelects: [
      {label: 'first', val: 1},
      {label: 'second', val: 2},
      {label: 'third', val: 3}
    ],...
```

So, in the first `select` value 1 must be selected, in the second - value 2, etc.

There are two steps to fix it:

1. trigger `change` event explicitly after you set the value
2. set the value after passing options

```
 mounted: function () {
    var vm = this
    $(this.$el)
    // first pass the options
      .select2({ data: this.options })
    // and then set the value
      .val(this.value)
    // trigger change event explicitly to let Vue know that it has to update DOM
      .trigger('change')
    // emit event on change.
      .on('change', function () {
        vm.$emit('input', this.value)
      })
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, Do I need to mess with the change event etc? Everything is working perfectly aside from when something is deleted.

Comment: Yes, you do. Otherwise, when the value changes programmatically (like in the case of deleting) you will have issues. Your v-model binding will not work properly. In this [article](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/) they say: If jQuery makes a change to an element that Vue is managing, Vue won't be aware of the change and is going to go right ahead and overwrite it in the next update cycle. Also see [Wrapper Component Example](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) by Vue.js.